# Using Office 365 now, can we pilot intune MDM on just 1-2 users or devices?

Tags: microsoft-intune, mdm

We have Microsoft hosting for exchange, office 365, defender for endpoint and are using the Office 365 MDM for device management.  We only have Azure AD basic not premium.

I've started an intune trial, created a Windows 10 VM as a device, added AD-based user, added the device and user to an intune group with policy and installed the company store app from the Windows store.  In that app, settings > sync runs without errors.

The device shows up in the intune device list and is compliant, but managed apps never sync.  They are stuck at "Waiting for install status"

My guess is this is because our MDM is Office 365, but I don't see any way in the admin panel or in any docs I've found to change that for just this test user, or the test device, or the intune group.

Is there some way to force intune to be the MDM for just this user, device, group?

Additional information:

On the device, Settings > Accounts > Access Work or School shows the device as "Connected to (company) MDM" (which will be the office 365 MDM?) and "Connected to (company)'s Azure AD"

In intune, DESKTOP-xxxxxx | Enrollment table shows "no results" for the device

Is that significant?  Joining AD and installing the company portal are both supposed to enroll the user or device if I'm reading the docs right.

Comment: I don’t think that matters. If you enroll it in Intune, that’s it. Be aware that my experience with Intune suggests that things can take up to 24 hours to apply. Did you wait that long?

Comment: @Appleoddity - yes, I waited a couple of days and the required app is never installed after multiple reboots and manual syncs.  I'm now trying deleting the existing app and re-publishing it as available for manual installs instead of as required to see if that helps.

Comment: What’s the status of the app on that endpoint? Can you confirm it is assigned but failing? Perhaps your assignment is wrong and it’s not even being applied. You should be able to get more details specifically about that app’s status on that endpoint.

Comment: @Appleoddity - Are there logs somewhere on the device? "Waiting for install status" was the managed app status in intune.  on the device it didn't show the required app at all in the company store.  The company store  shows "can access company resources" and manual sync seems OK